716 update held back for over a week on 24.04
I've been trying to update my 24.04 system for nearly 2 weeks and most of the updates are being held back.  Is there a distribution issue that is blocking the updates or might I have a problem on my system?  Today, there were 718 updates and only 2 were installed, the rest were held back.
At first, I assumed it was a phased update issue so I've been executing apt update / apt upgrade commands daily with no joy. I've been led to understand that phased  updates clear in a about a week so what I'm seeing seems excessive.

When you run sudo apt upgrade it will tell you if packages are being held back by phasing. If it doesn't say that, your package system is broken. Please run the command and let us know the results.

The following packages have been kept back: <list of 716 apps> 0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 716 not upgraded.

You can see if the packages are being phased by doing apt policy [packagename] on one of them. A phased package looks like this:
apt-cache policy python3-software-properties
python3-software-properties:
  Installed: 0.99.22
  Candidate: 0.99.22.5
  Version table:
     0.99.22.5 500 (phased 0%)
        500 http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/main amd64 Packages
 *** 0.99.22 500
        500 http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status

Example copied from this question The following packages have been kept back. But the packages are not "phased"
If they don't have the (phased percentage) in them, the package system is broken.
